# Are there relationships between Knowledge Management and Ontologies?

Tags: ontology

I'm working on a research project to develop an ontology for wetlands in PROTEGE, but I have doubts about the relationship between ontologies and knowledge management, I understand that ontologies are used for the representation of knowledge, but I can not find an academic text about the relationship between ontologies and knowledge management, specifically I find information on knowledge management.

Comment: I don't think that this question is a good fit for this site.  They claim that http://dba.stackexchange.com is supposed to be for 'data professionals', even with the domain name that makes it look like it's just for RDBMS administrators.  The Information Science site (which went under) would've been an even better site for this question.

Comment: Oh ... and ontologies are just a type of system that can be used for storing information, which can include the type of information of interest in knowledge management.

Comment: Perhaps _Wood, D. (ed.) Linked Enterprise Data_ is related to your question. Probably MDM (Master Data Management) is the most prominent application of ontologies in knowledge management.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different definitions of "ontology" out there. In my opinion this here is highly relevant in practice:

> An ontology is a formal, explicit specification of a shared conceptualization.

See [this article for a formal discussion](http://iaoa.org/isc2012/docs/Guarino2009_What_is_an_Ontology.pdf) (ignore the "math", read the text).

For `concept` and `conceptualization` (conceptual model) see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept)-[pedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_model) or page 15 in the reference above (semiotic triangle).

Therefore the most interesting questions in creating an ontology is, which [competency questions (see the section in ontology development 101)](http://protege.stanford.edu/publications/ontology_development/ontology101-noy-mcguinness.html) do you want your model or knowledge base to answer?

That settled, what does it have to do with knowledge management?

Wikipedia defines [Knowledge Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_management) as:

> Knowledge management (KM) is the process of creating, sharing, using and managing the knowledge and information of an organisation.

So ontologies can only be a tool in knowledge management (KM). So how do they help with KM?

Wherever you annotate data with terms from your ontology, it becomes more findable, accessible, interoperable and re-usable (see [FAIR data principles](https://www.force11.org/group/fairgroup/fairprinciples)) for humans and machines alike.

In addition it is easier to connect your data with other information (they facilitate data integration).